# Elasticsearch + Shield, security_exception happens when Document Level Security is enabled

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-shield

I've installed and set up Shield plugin for Elasticsearch 2.2.0. Then I added an admin user via the esusers realm. It all seems to work, I can authenticate and make queries, but when I try to enable some Document Level Security, it keeps giving this error response:

```
{
  "error": {
  "root_cause": [
     {
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized for user [my_user]"
     }
  ],
  "type": "security_exception",
  "reason": "action [indices:data/read/search] is unauthorized for user [my_user]"
   },
  "status": 403
}
```

I've tried many different query combinations. I have enabled all privileges so there shouldn't shouldn't be a problem with the action `indices:data/read/search`, although I also tried to specifically add this privilege. I tried both `analyzed` and `not_analyzed` fields, integers and strings, but no matter what I try I am getting this error. And only when I remove the "query" it starts working.

This is my defualt admin role, I've only added a query line to it:

```
admin:
  cluster: all
  indices:
    '*':
      privileges: all
      query: '{"term" : {"studentStudentId" : "0612112953"}}'
```